# data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values using IF statement

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb.net:

```
If(reader4.GetString(1) Is DBNull.Value, reader4.GetString(1), "0")
```

so if the data is null, it should just use the "0" but its still showing an error

what do i have wrong here?

Comment: I think you've got your logic backwards. Do you mean `If(reader4.GetString(1) Is DBNull.Value, "0", reader4.GetString(1))` ?

Comment: i did think that, but ive used If(reader4.GetString(1) Is DBNull.Value, "0", reader4.GetString(1)) and it shows the same error

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are testing for NULL and using the NULL value. Don't you mean: IS Not DBNull.Value?

Comment: Can you check reader4.IsDbNull(1) instead?

Comment: As @the_lotus points out, the `Is` operator is not the correct operator to use here.  You should use `=` or just call `isDbNull` as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
If(reader4.GetString(1) Is Nothing, "0", reader4.GetString(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is DBNull.Value is not an object but a value.  This means you need to use "equals" rather than "is".  One of the following should work:

```
If(reader4.GetString(1).Equals(DBNull.Value), "0", reader4.GetString(1))

If(reader4.GetString(1) = DBNull.Value, "0", reader4.GetString(1))

If(Convert.IsDBNull(reader4.GetString(1)), "0", reader4.GetString(1))
```

That said, it would be a good idea to make sure `reader4.GetString(1)` exists. Otherwise the dreaded "object not set to an instance of an object" exception may rear it's ugly head.

Answer (score 0):

It's better/simpler to use directly IsDbNull:

```
If(reader4.IsDBNull(1), "0", reader4.GetString(1))
```

This will work even if the column data-type is not string (int, date, etc) but comparing reader4.GetString with Nothing is limited because reader4.GetString excepts for other data-types column.